# Can't render data from API being passed down as props (ReactJS)

Tags: reactjs

I'm really stuck in trying to render some data being passed down as props. I'll include some code and definitions below, but if you feel that I need to include some further code snippets, please let me know (I'm really struggling to find what's causing the error, so I may have missed out the causal issue!).

I first take data from an API which is then used to populate a `UserList` component via useState (`setUsers(data`):

```
useEffect(() => {
  async function getUserList() {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const url =
        "API URL";
      const response = await fetch(url);
      const data = await response.json();
      setUsers(data);
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error("User list unavailable");
    }
    setLoading(false);
  }

  getUserList();
}, []);
```

If a user is clicked in the `UserList`, this changes the `selectedUser` state of the parent `Home` component to be the specific user's `unique_ID` via:

```
onClick={() => setSelectedUser(unique_ID)}
```

If the `selectedUser` changes, the `Home` component also does a more updated data fetch from the API to get all information relevant to the specific user via their `unique_ID`:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    async function getSelectedUserData() {
      try {
        const url = `API URL/${selectedUser}`;
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const data = await response.json();
        setSelectedUserData(data);
      } catch (error) {
        throw new Error("User data unavailable");
      }
    }

    getSelectedUserData();
  }, [selectedUser]);
```

The specific user data is then passed down as props to a child `UserInformation` component:

```
<UserInformation selectedUser={selectedUser} selectedUserData={selectedUserData} />
```

At this point, I can see all the data being passed around correctly in the browser React Developer Tools.

The `UserInformation` component then gets the data passed via props:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function UserInformation({ selectedUser, selectedUserData }) {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState({ selectedUserData });

  useEffect(() => {
    setCurrentUser({ selectedUserData });
  }, [selectedUser, selectedUserData]);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{selectedUserData.User_Firstname}</p>
      <p>{currentUser.User_Firstname}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default UserInformation;
```

And here is where I get stuck - I can't seem to render any of the data I pass down as props to the `UserInformation` component, even though I've tried a few different methods (hence the `<p>{selectedUserData.User_Firstname}</p>` and `<p>{currentUser.User_Firstname}</p>` to demonstrate).

I'd really appreciate any help you can give me with this - I must be making an error somewhere!

Thanks so much, and sorry for the super long post!

Comment: Might be an odd question since you've said you track the values using the dev tools, but did you try `console.log(currentUser, selectedUser, selectedUserData)` in the UserInformation component? We need to identify whether it is actually passed down at all

Comment: Hey - thanks for the reply!

I've run a console.log for `currentUser`, `selectedUser` and `selectedUserData`, and they're showing empty results until a specific user is selected. When a specific user is selected, the console.logs return the `unique_ID` as well as the API data, so I guess they're behaving as expected?

Comment: Let's go even further, I know it might look stupid, but console.log the values you hold inside `<p>`  to see if you get exactly what you expect to render, we can go step by step here haha

Comment: Just tried console.log in `<p>` to check that everything is getting pulled through ok. I start with 2 sets of empty values - I'm guessing this is a result of `useEffect`? After I click on a user, I then get all the information passed through that I'd expect: `unique_ID` and then an object with an array of objects worth of that user's specific data.

I really appreciate you helping by the way, so thanks once again!

Comment: No problem, we will get to the solution :) So `{currentUser.User_Firstname} or {selectedUserData.User_Firstname}` is an object? It should be a string as how I expect it, since if you try to render an Object, it is gonna show empty, is that maybe an issue? Basically `{selectedUserData.User_Firstname}` should be 'Antonio' or something like that, not `{foo: 'bar'}` Could you paste me the result of `console.log(selectedUserData.User_Firstname)`?

Comment: I get an `undefined` returned from `console.log(selectedUserData.User_Firstname)` :( Looks like we're getting closer to the issue though!

Comment: hmm Alright then, try pasting what comes from `console.log(selectedPatientData)`, also, I see this is the first time we mention `selectedPatientData` instead of `selectedUserData`, I guess that is correct still? Also take a look at what Mohamed wrote in the comment of his answer, might help with debugging

Comment: Hey - `selectedPatientData` is still correct (I just renamed everything to `user` to help with explaining my scenario on stack overflow.

I tried to console.log the `selectedUserData` and returned empty arrays with a length of 0.

Comment: Hmm, is an array what you expect to get from that? More importantly, do you receive the network call response as you expect? Mohamed just wrote a good note on hist last comment, if you expect this to be an array, dot notation is not the way to go

Comment: I was hoping for the data to be taken from the API via the `response.json();` to be stored as an object, so I could access the data via `{currentUser.User_Firstname}` or `{selectedUserData.User_Firstname}`, or something like that. I'm hoping to take the data from the API and render all the user details (such as firstname, lastname, date of birth, etc.), and change the data to suit the specific user whenver a new user is selected from the `UserList` component. So, I'm guessing an array isn't what I'd want here.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this (thanks to the help of Mohamed and Antonio above, as well as the reactiflux community).

```
import React from "react";

function UserInformation({ selectedUserData }) {
  const currentUserRender = selectedUserData.map(
    ({ User_Firstname, User_Lastname }) => (
      <div key={unique_ID}>
        <p>{User_Firstname}</p>
      </div>
    )
  );

  return (
    <div>
      {selectedUserData ? currentUserRender : null}
    </div>
  );
}

export default UserInformation;
```

As `selectedUserData` was returning an `array` instead of an `object`, I needed to `map` the data rather than call it with an `object` method such as `{selectedUserData.User_Firstname}`.

```
  const currentUserRender = selectedUserData.map(
    ({ User_Firstname, User_Lastname }) => (
      <div key={unique_ID}>
        <p>{User_Firstname}</p>
      </div>
    )
  );
```

The above snippet maps the selected data properties found inside `selectedUserData` (`{ User_Firstname, User_Lastname }`), with the whole `map` being called in the `return` via `{selectedUserData ? currentUserRender : null}`.

Hopefully my explanation of the above solution is clear for anyone reading, and a big thanks again to Mohamed and Antonio (as well as a few others in the reactiflux Discord community) for helping!

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to set the current user to an object with key "selectedUserData".

So if you want to access it you've to access it by this key name so change this line `currentUser.User_Firstname` to `currentUser.selectedUserData.User_Firstname`

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response.

I tried your suggestions - it's not crashing the app, but it's also still not rendering the data.

Comment: Can you do `console.log(currentUser)` and copy paste the log here?

Comment: I get the following:

`{...} / selectedUserData: Array [] / length: 0`

Comment: Bingo! `selectedUserData` is an Array so we can't access its content via the dot notation like an Object. Either change the `selectedUserData` to be an object or if it will only has a one and only one value then do the following: `currentUser.selectedUserData[0].User_Firstname`

Comment: From my above code, is the data from the API not stored as an object? I can't see where I've chosen to store the data as an array unless I'm currently fetching/storing it incorrectly? If possible, I'd like to be able to store the API data as an object so I can access it via `{currentUser.User_Firstname}`, for example. Thanks again for all your help so far!

Comment: Add this line `console.log(typeof data);` to both of these functions `getUserList()` `getSelectedUserData()` data before setting the state if either one of them is an Array then extract the data that you need from it and assign it to an Object then update the state with that Object.

Comment: I just tried to include the console.log in both `getUserList();` and `getSelectedUserData();` and both returned `undefined`. Oddly though, the data fetched from the API updates the state - which I can see in the react dev tools

Comment: This is weird are you sure you added them before setting the state and after you waited for fetching data to be complete?

Comment: Sorry - you're correct, I put the console.log in the wrong place (fatigue from trying to solve this issue, haha). `console.log(typeof data);` on both `getUserList();` and `getSelectedUserData();` returns `object`

Comment: Ok, this is good now we know that the data is an Object but here's a catch in JavaScript Arrays are Objects too!
Now replace the logging lines with `console.log(Array.isArray(data));` in both locations if one of them or both are true then we've located the culprit!

Comment: Thanks for continuing your help, Mohamed - really, thankyou! After amending the log to `console.log(Array.isArray(data));`, the console returns `true` for `getUserList();` and `getSelectedUserData();`

Comment: Don't mention it :D, Now you know that the data is indeed an `Array` you need now to extract what you want from it, assign it to an Object and update the state with that Object. Consider the following example: `const data = ['rizji', 'foo']; const [item] = data; const obj = { User_Firstname: item }; setState(obj);`

Comment: So as `selectedUserData` is an array, how would I access it's data in my `UserInformation` component? Currently it's passed through as a prop in the `function PatientNameHeader({ selectedPatient, selectedPatientData }) {` line.

Comment: I'm sorry I was busy but glad everything turned out well now. I mentioned early what you need to do to convert this Array to an Object, Do you have a question about it?. Also, About the solution I've some comments about it. If the data you fetch is an Array and will always has only one value then it's better to convert it to an Object. However, If it will have multiples of data then Array is the way to go.