# Cannot render data from API being passed from parent to child (ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just tried to follow [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63245058/cant-render-data-from-api-being-passed-down-as-props-reactjs) with no results for me.

The point is that I'm trying to get a selected pokemon from a component and pass down to another component. The data is correctly passed, some data are displayed, but with other (for example, the sprites) I got an error. I'm using `Context` by the way.

**PokemonContext.js**

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Context = React.createContext({});

export function PokemonsContextProvider({ children }) {
  const [favorites, setFavorites] = useState([]);

  return <Context.Provider value={{ favorites, setFavorites }}>{children}</Context.Provider>;
}

export default Context;
```

**App.js**

```js
<PokemonsContextProvider>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="/pokemons" element={<PokemonsList />} />
    <Route path="/favorites" element={<Favorite />} />
    <Route path="/pokemon/:name" element={<PokemonDetails />} />
    <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
  </Routes>
</PokemonsContextProvider>
```

**PokemonsDetails.js**

```js
const PokemonDetails = () => {
  const { name } = useParams();
  const [pokemon, setPokemon] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    pokemonService.pokemonDetail(name).then((res) => {
      setPokemon(res);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className="text-center mb-4">Details for {name.toUpperCase()}</h1>

      <PokemonCard pokemon={pokemon} />

      <div className="text-center">
        <Link className="btn btn-success mx-2 my-4" to="/favorites">
          Go back
        </Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

**PokemonCard.js**

```js
const PokemonCard = ({ pokemon }) => {
  return (
    <div className="card text-center bg-primary">
      <div className="card-body">
        <h5 className="card-title">{pokemon.name}</h5>
      </div>
      <ul className="list-group list-group-flush">
        <li className="list-group-item">Weight: {pokemon.weight}</li>
        <li className="list-group-item">Height: {pokemon.height}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PokemonCard;
```

When I add this line `<img className="card-img-top" src={pokemon.sprites.front_default} alt="Card image cap" />` to the `PokemonCard` component I got this error:

[image]

The data is correctly displayed when I console log it, so, I don't know why I'm having this error. If I inspect the *React Dev Tools* the data is in the component!

[image]

Comment: First, check in response, Do you get this image every object or not. Second, use this to ignore when it is undefined:src={pokemon.sprites?.front_default}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **PokemonCard.js** component is being rendered before the result of the request.

You can resolve this problem checking if there is a pokemon before use his props.

```
const PokemonCard = ({ pokemon }) => {
  return pokemon && (
    <div className="card text-center bg-primary">
      <img className="card-img-top" src={pokemon.sprites?.front_default} alt="Card image cap" />
      <div className="card-body">
        <h5 className="card-title">{pokemon.name}</h5>
      </div>
      <ul className="list-group list-group-flush">
        <li className="list-group-item">Weight: {pokemon.weight}</li>
        <li className="list-group-item">Height: {pokemon.height}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PokemonCard;
```